# Adding an extension to Phabricator causes PHP exceptions

Tags: php, phabricator

I managed to configure and set up Phabricator and everything's running ok but when I try to add an external extension to it I get PHP exceptions

I followed [How to modify values show in Phabricator task tile in backlog workflow mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482015/how-to-modify-values-show-in-phabricator-task-tile-in-backlog-workflow-mode)  to add the https://github.com/wikimedia/phabricator-extensions-Sprint  to my instance of the app.

When i try to edit a project after adding the extension i get:

```
Function name must be a string
/usr/local/Sprint/src/util/SprintValidator.php:6
```

And that's the content of SprintValidator.php

```
<?php

final class SprintValidator {

public function checkForSprint($showfields, $project_phid) {
 $show = $showfields($project_phid);
 if ($show == false) {
   return false;
 } else {
   return true;
 }
}

public function isSprint($project_phid) {
 $query = id(new SprintQuery())
     ->setPHID($project_phid);
 $issprint = $query->getIsSprint();
 return $issprint;
 }
}
```

PHP version installed: PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze25 with Suhosin-Patch

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Line 6 calliing a function (`$showfields($project_phid)`) and the error being "Function name must be a string", `$showfields` seems to be null or an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [this commit](https://github.com/wikimedia/phabricator-extensions-Sprint/commit/1befd0d9701ffe4035f4b005d6ad31988c95a1a9), the extension requires PHP 5.4.

Comment: that requirement would explain why I couldn't get the extension to work. Will test it today. Thanks!